# Mod_jk + Google OpenID = Error 502

Tags: mod-jk, google-openid

We use mod_jk to redirect Appserver like **httpd->mod_jk->glassfish** and works pretty well.
But when we want to login with Google OpenID, it shows "502 Bad gateway" error.
Anyone could help?

Here are my mod_jk settings:

```
#Set worker using ajp13
worker.list=works01,status
# Set properties for works01 (ajp13)
worker.works01.type=ajp13
worker.works01.host=192.168.2.114
worker.works01.port=8009
worker.works01.socket_keepalive=1
worker.works01.connection_pool_timeout=300

worker.status.type=status
```

Thanks a lot.